# How to read cell values that are dynamically generated using macros in c#?

Tags: c#

1. I have an excel file in which some cell values are generating dynamically using macro.
2. File is also read-only.
3. I have to read these dynamically generated values using c# code. 
   Use following **macro code** to generate cell values:

`**Sub abc()
Range("E5").Value = "string"
Range("E6").Value = 2
End Sub**`

Thank You...!

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need to connect to already opened excel file. 
If you use excelApp.Workbooks.Open, it is not reflecting sheet data updated by macros.
 Instead, try BindToMoniker method as follows:

```
  private void btnGetXLSValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

        object _row = 5;
        object _column = 5;
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        excelApp.Visible = false;
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook ;//= excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\July.xlsm", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        //Get a reference to the Workbook object by using a file moniker.
        //The xls was saved earlier with this file name.
        excelWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(@"C:\July.xlsm"); 

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
        string currentSheet = "July 2015";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
        string sValue = (range.Cells[_row, _column] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
        //string sValue = (range.Cells[_row, _column] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).get_Value(range).ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(sValue);
    }
```